# Can't access variable from window

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps API in React app but keep getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')` error. Here's the component that renders map:

```
const google = window.google;

const Map = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: defaultPosition,
            disableDefaultUI : true,
        });
    }, []);

    return <div id='map'></div>
}
```

What's interesting is that when I restart server, page renders without errors but when I reload it, everything crashes because `google` is somehow undefined

I load the script in `index.html` like that:

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script async
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY">
    </script>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App/App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Please show how you load the script for Google maps

Comment: I guess that in the final html your code is above the Google maps script. You can check it in the dev tools

Comment: I checked and it's not : (
Unfortunately, the problem is different. Also, somehow page loads without errors after I restart the server, but when I reload page in browser, it crashes